# How to save the names of muliple uploaded files to one field in yii 1

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x

I used `CUploadedFile` in order to upload multiple files in my web applcation. I used following code for this purpose:

```
public function actionCreate(){
    $model=new Status();
    $this->performAjaxValidation($model);
    if(isset($_POST['Status']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Status'];
        Yii::log("actionCreate actionCreate inside if"  .isset($_POST['Status']));
        $images = CUploadedFile::getInstancesByName('description');
        if(isset($images) && count($images)> 0)
        {

            foreach ($images as $image=>$pic)
            {
                if ($pic->saveAs(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/uploads/'.$pic->name,0777))
                {
                   $model= new Status();
                    $model->description =$pic->name;
                    $url = Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/uploads';
                    $model->insert();
                }
            }
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->status_id));
        }
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

When I upload multiple files, it saves all of them but with different ids(PK).I need to save all uploaded files names to the one field called `description`. How can I do it?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the question. What does the PK (primary key) do here? What do you mean by 'field'?

Comment: Now as I see the first answer, I now understand what you wanted. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing it this way

```
    public function actionCreate(){
    $model=new Status();
    $this->performAjaxValidation($model);
    if(isset($_POST['Status']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Status'];
        Yii::log("actionCreate actionCreate inside if"  .isset($_POST['Status']));
        $images = CUploadedFile::getInstancesByName('description');
        if(isset($images) && count($images)> 0)
        {
            // Create a blank array.
            $pic_name = array();
            foreach ($images as $image=>$pic)
            {
                if ($pic->saveAs(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/uploads/'.$pic->name,0777))
                {

                   //Put values in array.
                   $pic_name[$image] = $pic->name;
                   $url = Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/uploads';

                }
            }
            // If array has multiple values i.e. more than zero then and only then save it in description as a string.
            if(count($pic_name) > 0){
                $_pics = implode('|',$pic_name);

                // Do not create model everytime a new image is iterated
                $model= new Status();
                $model->description = $_pics;

                $model->insert();
            }

            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->status_id));
        }
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

I don't know what is the use of $url in the loop, that's why I have kept it as it is.